# Identifying an insect looking like a crumle

Tags: entomology, species-identification

Recently a little insect crawled over the carpet. First I did not notice, as its appearance is quite similar to the coloring of the carpet. Then I understood that it is not a rolling crumble, as the window and the door were closed.

I took it on an ordinary sheet of DIN A4 paper, but have not the slightest idea, what kind of insect it is. It makes the impression to have taken a shower of water and dust in a row.

**What's that insect called?**

The second photo gives an idea of the size, as it shows a drinking glass turned upside down.

*Note:* The place this insect was encountered is in eastern Germany

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: South-eastern Germany. Approximately at *50.993479, 13.649035*

Comment: looks really nice btw

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the nymph of a [masked hunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduvius_personatus).
They carmouflage in dust and sand.

[image]

Comment: if it really is what i belive it is, it can hurt you

Comment: I checked the article and to me it seems likely that your assumption is correct. However, this one appears to be really young and therefore not terrifying at all. But if its parents or older friends are around it could be a concern.

Comment: I thought the original image looked like an assassin bug covered in dirt, so this sounds right to me.